# Get aiohttp request response in callback with a infinite loop of asyncio task

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

**What I am doing**- I am trying to make multiple post requests(to the same URL with different parameters) in an infinite loop using asyncio and aiohttp.

```
def callback(response):
    print(response) 

async def make_request(session, payload, sema):
        async with sema, session.post(url=URL, headers=HEADERS, data=json.dumps(payload)) \
                as response:
            return await response.json()


async def generate_requests(payloads):
    tasks = []
    sema = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(value=100)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for payload in payloads:
            tasks.append(make_request(session, payload, sema))
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        print(results)


def run_asyncio_requests():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        for country in countries:
            cities = country.cities
            loop.run_until_complete(generate_requests(cities))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_asyncio_requests()
```

**Problem:** *run_asyncio_requests* function generates and make multiple requests(cities against a country) and then await for all responses for one country requests then executes the next country requests.

**What I want:** All countries' requests should be executed at once and callback(some kind of linked function with each request) function should handle each response because post request response time for each request is different. It should not wait to gather all the responses. Requests should be generated in each cycle(infinite-loop) and callback function in the background should be linked with each response. I know I am using *asyncio.gather* to get all responses until requests completed. But I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the same technique when invoking `generate_requests` that you did when invoking `make_request`:

```py
async def generate_all_countries():
    tasks = [generate_requests(country.cities) for country in countries]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(generate_all_countries())
```

Note that you don't need `run_asyncio_requests` as a separate sync function, you can simply invoke an async function using `asyncio.run()` and proceed from there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, your suggested code will generate all requests what about the callback function that will collect response when a response comes.

Comment: @Ahsanaslam Can't you just modify `make_request` and/or `generate_requests` to invoke the callback function you need?

Comment: I have no idea where to place callback function and one more thing is that In one cycle(infinite-loop) all countries request generated and await for all response but I need to continue infinite-loop that generates continuously and callback function handle each response without attaching other response.

Comment: *I have no idea where to place callback function* - you could call it at the end of `make_request` or at the end of `generate_requests`, depending on what you want the callback to observe. Or am I somehow misunderstanding what you want to achieve?

Comment: The above code is working fine but the problem is that in infinite-loop cycle my code wait for each cycle(for country in countries:) generated requests and when all response for one cycle completed it then generates next cycle requests. I want a mechanism in which code should not wait for each cycle response. A callback function should automatically trigger when a response come from post request.

Comment: @Ahsanaslam Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "infinite-loop cycle". Can you update the question with the code that better reflects your actual use case?

Comment: I am using while True an infinite-loop. And one cycle means when "for country in countries:" completed.

Comment: @Ahsanaslam But you can add the same `while True` in `generate_all_countries`. And you can still invoke a function of your choosing (or one provided by the caller) inside `make_request` or `generate_requests`. What additional "trigger" do you need?